# Select-String returns multiple lines

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell and want to match a string in a variable. Consider this example:

```
$string = ipconfig
Select-String -InputObject $string -Pattern '127.0.0.1'
```

Returns the whole string. Not just `'127.0.0.1'.` So I tried:

```
Select-String -InputObject $string -SimpleMatch '127.0.0.1' -AllMatches
```

Which also returns the entire string. What am I doing wrong? I just want to see the match, not other lines.

Comment: Does `$string | Select-String '127.0.0.1'` help?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As [arco444](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115685/arco444) has mentioned in comments, you can simply write:
  `> $string | Select-String -Pattern "127.0.0.1"`
For more examples, see [Select-String Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-5.1).

Answer (score 1):

Select-String returns a `.Matches` property that is a collection of the matches. The `.Value` property of that is the value that matched:

```
$string = ipconfig
(Select-String -InputObject $string -Pattern '127.0.0.1').Matches.Value
```

This example would return all the values that looked like an IP address:

```
(Select-String -InputObject $string -Pattern '\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Note that if you are matching against an exact pattern (e.g no wildcards/regex) then you could just use `-Quiet` which returns true/false based on whether the pattern matched:

```
$MyString = '127.0.0.1'
If (Select-String -InputObject $string -Pattern $MyString -Quiet) { $MyString }
```

Then